# Make a call from a string using a data frame R

Tags: r, string, dataframe

Let's suppose I have a DB with 4 variables (A,B,C,D) with 2 rows:

```
A B C D  
1 1 2 3  
1 1 4 5
```

I want to do a mathematical operation which is unknown a priori put it is given by a string, for example:

```
my_string <- "A x B - C x D"
```

In my DB the first two numbers (A,B) are calibration parameters in an algorithm and C and D are data. I need to do the operation that tells the string many times, and unknown times until convergence.

Since what I've read I think this could be done by using a Call function. For example I have a function:

```
my_function <- function(string, data){  

  #do what I have to do  
return(something)  
}
```

And I should repeat `my_function` until I found the suited A and B.

How could I do that if the "instruction" is given by a string?

PS: The parameters and data are shown in the same dataframe, they could be in two different DB if helps solve it faster, I have no trouble with that.

Comment: Yes, I'ts "A x B-C x D" for example. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval(parse(text="2+3"))` will produce `5`, is this what are you looking for?

it works with variables as well

```
d <- 4
eval(parse(text="d+3"))
```

will produce 7

UPDATE

something like this?

```
d <- data.frame(a = 11:20, b = 1:10)

f <- function(cmd, data) {
    with(data, eval(parse(text=cmd)))
}

q <- f(cmd="2*a-3*b", d)
print(q)
```

produce

```
[1] 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10
```

Comment: Yes it works partially. I have "d" in a dataframe, which ll call "data". The string would be: "d+3", so what I must do is before every variable write a "data". Which would look like:

eval(parse(texto = "data$d + 3"))

¿Is there a fast way to do this? Since I wont know a priori the structure of the string.

Comment: @FelipeGonzalez Just hope that no one runs `f("eval(parse(text = 'rm(list = ls())'),envir = .GlobalEnv)",d)`.

Comment: Exactly like the update! It is a model (which does not exists) in which someone could use a mathematical structure that isn't known a priori. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A better way of doing this is to use `eval(substitute()` rather than `eval(parse(text = ...))`:

```
d <- data.frame(a = 11:20, b = 1:10)

f1 <- function(cmd,data){
    eval(substitute(cmd),data,parent.frame())
}

> f1(a+b,d)
 [1] 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30
> f1(2*a-b,d)
 [1] 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

Comment: mmm... He asked `mathematical operation which is unknown a priori put it is given by a string`. I think `parse` is right on spot

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux The answer the OP _thinks they want_ is not always the answer that is ideal, or even recommended best practice.

Comment: Well, my guess would be operation is entered from some UI, and passed down to R kernel, so yes, I would venture it is a string

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Fine! But these questions exist for more than the needs of the OP. Many other people over a period of years may stumble across this question who's needs are not exactly the same as the OP. And those people should be notified that, in general, there is a better approach to this type of problem.

Comment: In fact what I have behind is a model in which the mathematical calculus , ideally, must be hidden from the user.